# Swapping mupltiple words and numbers that occur in one line using SED

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I have a large file where in every line it shows :

```
OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12) 
OCCUPY 45 EVERY PIC X(21) 
OCCUPY 98 EVERY PIC F(A0)
OCCUPY 21 EVERY PIC T(BC)
```

And desired output should be :

```
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY 
PIC X(21) OCCUPY 45 EVERY
PIC F(A0) OCCUPY 98 EVERY
```

and so on.

So, this is just an example, but in the file there are lots of lines with different chars/numbers near PIC and different numbers near OCCUPY.

So far, I tried executing :

```
sed -E 's/(.*OCCUPY\ )(0([A-Z]\([0-9])\)(.*EVERY\ )(.*PIC\ )(([0-9]\([0-9]+\))/\3\4\1\2/'
```

```
sed -E 's/((OCCUPY )([A-Z]\([0-9]))\)(.*EVERY )(.*PIC)(([0-9]\([0-9]))/\3\4\1\2/'
```

But, it didn't help .

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by your sample, your sed command seems too complicated. What about this simpler version?

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(PIC .*\)/\2 \1/'
```

[update] Your lines are more complicated than stated in your post. They are like:

```
MS-MSG OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12) 0012345
```

And you want:

```
PIC 32(12) OCCUPY 12 EVERY
```

Then, all you have to do is add those extra characters to the left-side of the substitution command, but *outside* the parentheses (whose content is used to build the new string):

```
sed 's/.* \(OCCUPY .*\) \(PIC [^ ]*\).*/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, can you please help me with this .. If I have words and numbers at the start and finish, how can I do that ? ex : "MS-MSG OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12) 0012345 "          I tried `` sed -r 's/(OCCUPY[0-9]+) (EVERY+) (PIC[A-Z]([A-Z][0-9])+)/\3 \1 \2/' `` , but didnt work

Comment: Thank you for the response, I just saw it!. Definitely helpful!!
I was trying to use your script, but in some of the lines the words are splitting, and the script is not changing for that : 

`OCCUPY 12 EVERY

                
PIC 32(12)` 
So, OCCUPY 12 EVERY is in one line and PIC 32(12) one line below...Do you might know how to change this ? I would appreciate your help!!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you mean the input line is split over two lines (a case which my script is not ready for), or that my script is splitting lines (I don't see why it would). In any case, I guess you should ask another question on S.O., giving full details on input, actual output and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

if your data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(OCCUPY.+EVERY).+(PIC \S+)/\2 \1/' d
```

Comment: this command only works with d files? I wanted to try this on my file. If for example, I have  " MS-MSG  OCCUPY 12 EVERY PIC 32(12)   0012345 " ?

Comment: substitute `d` with your filename